# Definition of Canonically polarized manifold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, kahler-manifolds

Does anyone have a reference for the definition of a canonically polarized manifold? Typically, at least from what I have seen, a polarized manifold is a compact Kähler manifold $X$ together with an ample line bundle $L \to X$. I cannot seem to find a definition of canonically polarized, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Canonically polarised means that the polarising line bundle L is a power of the canonical bundle (top exterior power of the cotangent bundle). In particular it only makes sense if the canonical bundle is ample.

Comment: @Johnny Thank you!